# API Gateway cache for 301 and 302 responses

Tags: redirect, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have an endpoint which performs redirect (returns 302 status code + Location header).

I'm trying to enable API Gateway cache for it. But it seems that API gateway caches only 200 responses (well so far I saw caching of 404s too).

Note, when I set to return 200, cache works as expected.

How is it possible to cache redirects too?

My serverless template fragment:

```
redirectFunction:
handler: handler.redirect
events:
  - http:
      path: /v1/redirect/{someParameter+}
      method: get
      caching:
        enabled: true
        cacheKeyParameters:
          - name: request.header.Some-header
          - name: request.path.someParameter
```